# Changing the screen resolution on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, display, parallels, macbook-air

I am running 12.04 within Parallels 7 on an 11" MacBook Air.

I'm trying to set the display resolution to the native 1366 x 768 but Ubuntu doesn't list this as an option.  How can I add the correct resolution to the options?

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html

Comment: See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine). I made a comment to my answer regarding setting the geometry from EFI BIOS. This may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Search for the line with `quiet splash`, and change it to `quiet splash nomodeset`. Save the file.
Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your VM.

In most of the cases this will help.

Comment: That should be "quiet splash" instead of "quiet spasch".

Comment: This did not work for me. But this answer did: http://askubuntu.com/a/256269/1574